# Spring 3 and JAXB

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jaxb

I have implemented a basic mvc app using Spring, i annotated my class as follows

I have added Spring oxm to my pom, but not added jaxb or json handlers.

My configuration is pretty much empty.

So my question is how is spring producing xml output when i call a GET in my controller and returning the following object in xml.

Where is it finding the xml marshaller, is it in the spring-oxm? is there default?

Is this the httpmessageconverters? i set my controller tot he following:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/state",  method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE  })
public ResponseEntity<GameState> getGameState(.. response,... request) {..}
```

my object :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "door")
public class GameState {

    private int id;

    private String state;

    public GameState() {
        super();
    }

    public GameState(int id, String state) {
        this.id = id;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 6 has JAXB built into the distro, you are specifying the container that ur looking by the

> @XmlRootElement(name = "door")

If you will need more information on JAXB bundling here is the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) .